# How to trace requested Memory References?

Tags: 14.04, pagestack

i'm working on page replacement algorithm. for testing algorithm, i'm trying to analyse pattern in which memory would be requested. Can i get list of requested page to page replacement algorithm in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `strace` to see what happens on the system call level;

But it seems like you will need even more detail, that is, information about what happens inside the kernel.

Either there is logging output you need to find and enable, or you need to add it yourself; In both cases, the starting point is the kernel development documentation, and of course the source.
Probably you are already reading that - otherwise, I propose to download the kernel source (or get a git clone of it) and look into the docs directory.